# how do I make rails rspec tests for default timestamps (created_at, updated_at)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

How do write `rspec` tests to ensure `created_at` and `updated_at` attributes are not `null` for  model data in rails.

Comment: I don't think you need those test cases. The timestamps have not null constraints

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of the object and test it like so:

```
 expect(foo.created_at).not_to be_nil
 expect(foo.updated_at).not_to be_nil
```